# Is it correct to say, "Jamie and I look forward to seeing you and Kate on Friday?"

Tags: pronouns

Pronouns can be so confusing.  Is this appropriate or is there a preferred structure other than this?

Comment: After reading the title alone, I was thinking that the confusion was on the usage of "look forward to *seeing* you and Kate", which happens to be the correct usage. Non-native speakers are prone to the mistake of using "look forward to *see* you and Kate".

Comment: What about "Jamie and I are looking forward to..."? Would it be correct to use a present continuous?

Comment: Yes. It is still present continuous. Thanks for bringing this up. This is the instance when it gets most confusing.

Comment: @TheOm3ga : Your question makes me think - Can there ever be an instance of the phrasal verb "Look/looking forward to" followed by a form of verb other than present continuous?

Answer (score 19):

Your sentence is perfectly correct. *Jamie and I* is right because it's a subject (*Jamie and me* is a common mistake) and *you and Kate* is correct too. Both are in a natural order, as well: it's common to put *I*, *me*, or *myself* last in a list and *you* or *yourself* either first or last. *I and Jamie* is correct but odd, and *Kate and you* sounds pretty strange; many people write something like *Kate and yourself* as an alternative.

Comment: Nice - but is there a custom of putting ladies first, so "Kate and yourself" ?

Comment: I think that sounds a bit contrived. There's no (modern, at least) custom of putting females first.

Comment: That alternative was the first thing to come to my mind as well.

Comment: We place *I* last (as done in the question) because it then fits properly into its place in the sentence: *(Jamie and) I look forward to seeing you and Kate* since *Jamie look forward to* is grammatically incorrect.

Comment: @Karl: So are you suggesting "Karl and Jamie look forward to the match on Tuesday." would not be a correct sentence? Since there are two subjects in both examples, I doubt that motivation.

Comment: @oKtosiTe, of course you're right. I'm going to ask that you accept that I've had a long day and pretend that never happened...

Comment: @Karl: Pretend that _what_ never happened? ;-)

Comment: I don't think *Kate and yourself* would be correct here, since *yourself* is a reflexive pronoun and, in this case *you* is not the agent doing the *seeing*, so a reflexive pronoun is inappropriate.

Comment: In my experience, couples tend to have a commonly-used name order among their friends. I would just use that, unless it's a special occasion and you want to highlight one of the two for some reason.

Comment: @Dancrumb: The use of *yourself* and *myself* to stand for *you* and *me* in lists is contested but common, especially in formal or business speech in American English. I think people are uncomfortable saying *you* and *me* simply because they're rather short and sharp, even though they're preferable.

Comment: @Jon: I've heard them used in NE England in an attempt to sound more formal or 'posh'. I agree that it's commonly used. I think it's an unfortunate case of convention over correctness, but far be it from me to try and stifle the evolution of a whole language :o)

Comment: JoseK, one would not say, "look forward to seeing Kate and yourself" because yourself is a reflexive pronoun (that is used obsessively lately and nearly always incorrectly). Only YOU can see "yourself".